# Inserting data into mysql from array in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a database `test` with table name `table` with two columns `user` & `email`.
Whats wrong with my below code? Am not able to add the array `$u` to my db

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("test", $con);

    $user = "safwan";
    $email = "esafw@jdjd.com";

    $u = array ( user => $user,
                    email => $email
                   );

    $q =   "INSERT INTO table  VALUES ($u)";

    mysql_query($q) OR die(mysql_error());

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: Because.. It's an array? **edit** Also: Stop using mysql_* functions, use PDO or mysqli_* instead. (you're vulnerable to mysql injection this way)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of issues:

1. You're trying to insert an array directly into your database. You need to be accessing the values individually.
2. You should use quotes around strings, that includes when they are keys in an array
3. You need to learn about SQL injections
4. You should consider migrating away from mysql_* functions since [they will soon be going away.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3656047#3656047)
5. table is a MySQL keyword and needs backticks if it's actually the table name

   $user,
                       'email' => $email
                      );

       $q =   "INSERT INTO table (user, email) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($u['user'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($u['email'])."')";

       mysql_query($q) OR die(mysql_error());

       mysql_close($con);
       ?>

Or:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("test", $con);

    $user = "safwan";
    $email = "esafw@jdjd.com";

    $q =   "INSERT INTO table (user, email) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."')";

    mysql_query($q) OR die(mysql_error());

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: 4. `table` is a MySQL keyword and needs backticks if it's actually the table name.

Comment: I've added it to the growing list :)

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the MySQL datatypes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-types.html

You'll have to loop over arrays and add the elements individually. I would also suggest using something else such as MySQLi or PDOs for security http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

In fact, with PDOs you could "add arrays" (because of the way it's designed).

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name=? AND password=?);
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['username'], $_GET['password']));
```

I'm not going to go over too much detail because you should really learn one of the newer technologies. Just a lot more secure with prepared statements and SQL injection and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing your query. It will appear like :

```
"INSERT INTO table  VALUES (array)".
```

Surely what you don't want.

You can construct insert query by looping through the array or directly using :

```
INSERT INTO table  VALUES ($user, $email)
```